# Does Crew Dragon have a quick-release hatch?

Tags: spacecraft, safety, dragon-v2

After today's Crew Dragon launch was scrubbed, it took the pad ninjas at least ten minutes to open the hatch.  One of the major criticisms of the Apollo Block 1 hatch design after the Apollo 1 fire was that opening it was a slow, complicated procedure.  (The other was that since it opened inwards, it was impossible to open against a pressure differential.)

Does the Crew Dragon hatch have a quick-release option in case the crew need to get out in a hurry?

Comment: thank you for using the name "pad ninjas".

Comment: @tedder42 "pad gimps" is more like it. https://www.vulture.com/2014/10/steve-hibbert-gimp-pulp-fiction-interview.html

Comment: Comment instead of answer because I don't have references, but I'm fairly certain it has an explosive-release hatch, but it's a permanent one-time operation, so it's better to let the pad ninjas do it the slow way.

Comment: As far as I know, NASA requires that the astronauts must be able to get to the escape baskets within 90 seconds. Boeing demonstrated less than 60 seconds for the Starliner. Not sure if this also applies with the hatch closed, though.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this...

Comment: I'm pretty sure a bunch of that 10 minutes was gas testing for noxious fumes before opening the hatch.